# Change order in List depending on list items

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list for example:

```
list = ["Create Apple Pie from apples, pie crust etc", "Create pie crust from eggs, flour etc", "Create x from y", "create y from z"]
```

What I want the list to look like is for all independent items to appear first before their dependencies.

```
list = ["Create y from z", "create x from y", "Create pie crust from eggs...", "Create apple pie from pie crust"]
```

The list items follow a generic order, Create abc from xyz.

I tried using regular expression and i think am able to retrieve the item name but lost on how it should traverse and reorder. happy to clarify more if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to maintain some kind of relationship between items.

```
l = ["Create Apple Pie from apples, pie crust etc", "Create pie crust from eggs, flour "]

d={'apple pie':'pie crust','pie crust':'flour'}  # dictionary with keys and values

"Create {} from {}.".format(*d.keys())  # using format and unpacking keys with *

#output
'Create apple pie from pie crust.'

"Create {} from {}.".format(*d.values()) # using format and unpacking values with *

#output
'Create pie crust from flour.'
```